# PHP server running slow on win 10 Home

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I have recently purchased a win10 Home PC 64-bit OS and mostly use it for my personal PHP projects. I use AMPPS and USBWEBSERVER [php/mysql].

I notice all my scripts are heavily running slow. A simple SELECT query takes over 30+ seconds.

I use localhost in the URL or sometimes 127.0.0.1, never the IP since it uses DHCP.

I have tried updating the hosts file, yet to no avail the sluggishness exists.

Any suggestions?

The same setup on XP/7/8.1 enterprise editions works like a charm or the way I have expected it to be.

Comment: Minor style thing: ending your sentences with a "." would by quite useful.

Comment: From experience I'd say it's probably some `extension` you have enabled in your `php.ini` that you might not even need that is hanging the scripts for no reason. Disable all extensions that aren't needed and your scripts should run normally.

Comment: Windows 10 !== LAMP, by the way...